# How to get which image has been set for the UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton

In my app I have a context where I am changing the  images of the UIButton using the NSTimer like follows

```
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(LoadImageToTheAdButton) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


-(void)LoadImageToTheAdButton
{
     NSString *strPath = [arrPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        strPath = [strPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Folder"];
        strPath = [strPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[arrAdImgNames objectAtIndex:intAdImgIndex]];
        UIImage *imgForAdBtn = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:strPath];
        [btnAd setBackgroundImage:imgForAdBtn forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        if(intAdImgIndex < [arrAdImgNames count]-1)
        {
            intAdImgIndex++;
        }
        else
        {
            intAdImgIndex = 0;
        }
}
```

Now on click of the button **i need to know which image was set on the button I mean, I need the image name **

**I need that because based on that image I am loading some links,**

How can I do that can any buddy help me out please,,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cannot you also save the name in a property of your view controller (updating them both together)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the name of the image currently set on the button, all you can get is the memory address referencing the image. A good alternative would be to use the buttons tag property to specify the index in an array that contains the image names. For example:

```
myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"something.png",@"somethingElse.png",@"etc.png", nil];

- (void)myMethod:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *imageNameSelected = [myArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
}
```

So for this example, when you set the buttons image to "something.png" you would set the buttons tag property to "0", or "1" for "somethingElse.png" etc...

Answer (score 0):

try setAccessibility* property in any view . these are very helpful . i get image name by using this property in my app.